# how to union multiple index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to find union of index of multiple dataframes, in pandas union can only be used for 2 indexes at a time, so I have to do it multiple times like below. I am wondering if I can do it using only one line? Thanks

```
NewIdx = pd.Index(Idx1.union(Idx2), 
                  name = 'depth')
NewIdx=pd.Index(NewIdx.union(Idx3), 
                  name = 'depth')
NewIdx=pd.Index(NewIdx.union(Idx4), 
                  name = 'depth')
NewIdx=pd.Index(NewIdx.union(Idx5), 
                  name = 'depth')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

Idx1 = pd.Index(['A', 'B'])
Idx2 = pd.Index(['A', 'C'])
Idx3 = pd.Index(['D', 'E'])
Idx4 = pd.Index(['A'])

out = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), [Idx1, Idx2, Idx3, Idx4])
# Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Index.union()` returns an index, you can just chain the commands and rename it at the end:

```py
newIdx = pd.index(
    Idx1.union(Idx2).union(Idx3).union(Idx4).union(Idx5),
    name = 'depth')
```